# How to add an afterRender to a data-bind="with:

Tags: knockout.js

I need to add an afterRender callback to an existing data-bind statement, but I'm struggling with the syntax.

Here's the code I need to add the afterRender to, which currently renders correctly:

```
    <div data-bind="with: detail">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="header">
                <span data-bind="html: headerMainSegment"></span>
                <span data-bind="text: headerSecondSegment"></span>
                <div data-bind="text: rollupSegment"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here's what I have tried, but the content disappears:

```
    <div data-bind="with: { data: detail, afterRender: customCode }">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="header">
                <span data-bind="html: data.headerMainSegment"></span>
                <span data-bind="text: data.headerSecondSegment"></span>
                <div data-bind="text: data.rollupSegment"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I added the customCode method to the viewmodel, but all of the data attributes appear to be null when rendered.

Comment: Did you try `data-bind="with: { data: detail }, afterRender: customCode"`?

Comment: I get the same result, empty span tags.

Comment: I don't see any indication in the docs that Knockout supports `afterRender` for `with` bindings. Just `template` and `foreach`. `with` doesn't have two forms, like `foreach`, to handle additional parameters.

Comment: if you're prefixing the members with `data`, it needs to have the dollar sign (`$data`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `afterRender`, you'll need to use the `template` binding instead.

```
<div data-bind="template: { data: detail, afterRender: customCode }">
   <div class="row">
        <div class="header">
            <span data-bind="html: headerMainSegment"></span>
            <span data-bind="text: headerSecondSegment"></span>
            <div data-bind="text: rollupSegment"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Another option is to create a custom binding that does your "custom code" and have it run after the `with` binding:

```
<div data-bind="with: detail, customCode: detail">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

The custom binding would be something like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.customCode = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, vm, context) {
        ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());     // access the value so we're updated when it changes

        // do my custom code with the element... 
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you.  The addition to the bindingHandlers was the solution I ended up using.

Comment: Having troubles with the first solution, bindings within get $parent is not defined.